# Passed out asleep / Slept

Tags: grammar

In *Inside Out* animation when Riley fall asleep, her emotion Joy says "We're out". She actually wants to say *we fell asleep*. So I think Joy wanted to say *We're passed out asleep* and the writer abbreviated it to *We're out*... Sorry for bad English ...

What is the difference between two:

> He's passed out asleep.
>
> He slept.

And is the first sentence "He is passed out asleep." Or "He has passed out asleep."?

Comment: While *passed out* can mean being soundly asleep, properly it refers to someone who is unconscious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add "passed out asleep" to Joy's quote.

"We're out" is a play on words of sorts. In radio communication, people use the word "over" when they are done talking, and "out" when they are done with an entire conversation. As [one website explains](http://www.dyerlabs.com/communications/procedural_codes.html):

> The term "over" is used with radio connections when only one person can speak (successfully) at a time. It means "I have finished speaking for the moment, but am expecting your reply - go ahead". "Out" means "I have finished speaking, and the conversation is finished; don't reply".

So, when Joy says, "We're out," that alludes to an end of communications for the night, and it's also a play on words (meaning "we're out cold," or "we're out sleeping" or "we're passed out").

Sure, Joy could have said, "We're asleep," but the cute radio pun would have been lost.

Answer (score 0):

*Slept* is the past tense of *sleep* - it means you fell asleep, completed sleeping, and are now awake.

*He's passed out asleep* refers to his current state, which is "now sleeping."  When you say someone is "passed out asleep" - they aren't currently awake.

Comment: Is it "He is passed out asleep." Or "He has passed out asleep."???

Comment: Is it present perfect??